# Hash function for PHP associative arrays

Tags: php, hash, hashmap

I understand that PHP associative arrays are stored in a Hash Table.
What hashing function is used for the string 'keys' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [zend/hash.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.10/Zend/zend_hash.h#L237):

```
/*
 * DJBX33A (Daniel J. Bernstein, Times 33 with Addition)
 *
 * This is Daniel J. Bernstein's popular `times 33' hash function as
 * posted by him years ago on comp.lang.c. It basically uses a function
 * like ``hash(i) = hash(i-1) * 33 + str[i]''. This is one of the best
 * known hash functions for strings. Because it is both computed very
 * fast and distributes very well.
 *
 [...]
 *                  -- Ralf S. Engelschall 
 */

static inline ulong zend_inline_hash_func(const char *arKey, uint nKeyLength)
```

Comment: can you please provide the link for this ?